# How to redirect domain to domain path using Cloudfront or Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have an S3 bucket that serves static HTML in `/id` and `/en`

For example, I have domain https://www.myblog.com, I want to redirect to https://www.myblog.com/en or https://www.myblog.com/id based on client geolocation

Is there any way to achieve this with CloudFront OR Route 53?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Serverless approach:

Attach a lambda@edge to the CloudFront distribution. In the lambda@edge, check the geolocation of the client IP and return 301 redirect accordingly.

#### Non-serverless approach:

Spin up two public EC2's (say A and B). Configure A and B to redirect traffic to `/id` and `/en` respectively. Then make a Route 53 geolocation routing to those two instances.

If anyone has any better approaches, please let me know in the comment.